# Would a HR be displeased if I give her work phone number to my close friend who is keen to apply for a job?

Tags: human-resources, internship, contact

From last December to January, I interned at a MNC. That company is currently recruiting some roles. My friend is keen to applying for a particular role X, so I gave the HR's contacts details (work phone number) to my friend and told her to include the department and key team leader that I used to work for and also that I was the one who gave her the contact number. My friend got a whole blue-tick from the HR.

Comment: Is “bue tick” good or bad? (Really, I’m not familiar with the term.) The answer to that question would answer your question, no?

Comment: I'd never heard of "getting a blue tick" before, but apparently (according to Urban Dictionary) it means "left on read" (i.e. a message sent with the expectation of reply, is received but ignored). Perhaps the OP can clarify whether this is the intended meaning, that his friend approached HR but was ignored.

Comment: @Steve Sorry for the unclear information. I was referring to my friend being ignored by the HR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would a HR be displeased if I give her work phone number to my close
> friend who is keen to apply for a job?

Never give out non-public contact details without permission.

You should have asked the HR rep first.

Comment: From this experience I have learned a lesson. Initially, I am quite worried that it would affect my chances of getting into that company too next time, but there is also nothing I can do about it now. I learned my lesson the hard way.

Answer (score 2):

The blue tick really doesn't have anything to do with it. HR isn't going to spite a good candidate just because you decided to something that may displease them.

Some companies have an application process that is designed to be fair, so that candidates are treated equally and without bias. Trying to short-circuit this process to give a friend a benefit can very easily cause HR to be annoyed.

In addition, it is inappropriate to give out email addresses and phone numbers without permission. The exception would be if that email address is listed in job advertisements.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I guess I have learned my lesson the hard way and think twice next time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the phrase "blue tick". However, it is a bad idea to give your friend the HR contacts. By doing so, you just annoy the HR staff. Also, giving your friend the contacts usually doesn't give him or her any advantages.

Recruitment decisions are usually based on interviews in Western countries, despite the fact that personal connection may give one some advantages in countries, like China. In China, if you say you know somebody the interviewers know, your chances of being engaged are greater. But if the HR staff know that the phone number is from you and they dislike this, you will be adversely affected.

In addition, what if a lot of people knew the phone number from their friends and made the calls? The staff cannot take up all these calls and they have other tasks to do. That is why I reckon that HR staff do not welcome the calls of this sort.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I guess I have learned my lesson the hard way, I (myself) was still initially hoping to get into that company for a job after I graduate in another 1.5 years' time. I hope all is well by then.